# some files in output directory are locked even the executable is stop running

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I found sometime some files in output directory is locked even after executable finishes running. I have to restart the Visual studio to solve it. Is there simple way to get out from there?

Comment: Maybe you could give us a hint about which files these are?

Answer (score 1):

Please learn about this tool, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

It can easily tell you what's up.

Answer (score 0):

Try [VSCommands 2010 extension](http://vscommands.com/download).
When error ocurrs saying that file is locked then just right-click (on error in error list window in Visual Studio) and select Apply Fix. This will tell you which application is using the process and try to fix that for you.

[image]
[image]